# jqplot pie chart percentage adding

Tags: jqplot

Consider this code snippet:

```
function drawChart() {
      var slice_1 = ['A', 15];
      var slice_2 = ['B', 40];
      var slice_3 = ['C', 50];
      var slice_4 = ['D', 40];
      var series = [slice_1, slice_2, slice_3,slice_4];
      var data = [series];

      var options = {
        seriesColors: ["#00aeef", "#FFBF00", "#0CDA08", "#FF1926"],
        seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer
        },
        legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
      };

      $.jqplot('chartDivId', data, options);
    }
```

In the above, how do i get percentage inside the pie chart? I tried many things but can;t make it work.

I added this:

```
  rendererOptions: {
          // Put data labels on the pie slices.
          // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
          showDataLabels: true,
          dataLabels: 'value',
          dataLabelFormatString:'%.4f'
        }
```

But percentage didn't appear inside the pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

I used the above snippet (the one you posted) and I was able to display labels in 'percentages'

You just need to use `showDataLabels: true` inside `rendererOptions`
By default, `showDataLabels` displays the labels in percentages.

No need for the code below. Remove these two lines

```
dataLabels: 'value',
dataLabelFormatString:'%.4f'
```

Here's a working JSFiddle for your code : [Pie Chart - Show labels in percentages](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/jytuu1zp/)

Also make sure that you add `rendererOptions` inside `seriesDefaults`

You can also check the example over here: [jqPlot - Pie Chart](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php)

Hope it helps.